# Unity Two states prefab animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d game with unity 4.6 and c#. I need to create two types of door. First one is initially opened and when some event happed the door is closed. I've made this using unity Animation object. Now second door type is same door but initially it closed and after some event it opened. So my question is there any way to create one prefab, add two animations and two initial states and after init setup one of two states, and play one of two animations on some event, or should it be two separate prefabs with separate animations?

Animation is simple, I just animate scale of sprite's transform.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using legacy Animation component, look at Unity's [Animator](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animator.html). It's a little bit more complicated, and requires more work to learn and set up, but it's much more agile. I think [this video](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth/single-doors) explains how it is used in Unity's Stealth project for doors in particular.